# tf transform tutorial issue (past extrapolation)

Tags: ros, transforms, rospy, tf-tutorial, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working through the `python` [tf tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Time%20travel%20with%20tf%20%28Python%29) and am having an issue with an extrapolation into the past. Here's the section:

> So let's go back to where we ended in the previous tutorial. Go to your package for the tutorial:

```
$ roscd learning_tf
```

> Now, instead of making the second turtle go to where the first turtle is now, make the second turtle go to where the first turtle was 5 seconds ago. Edit nodes/turtle_tf_listener.py:

```
try:
    now = rospy.Time.now() - rospy.Duration(5.0)
    listener.waitForTransform("/turtle2", "/carrot1", now, rospy.Duration(1.0))
    (trans, rot) = listener.lookupTransform("/turtle2", "/carrot1", now)

except (tf.Exception, tf.LookupException, tf.ConnectivityException):
```

The referenced "previous tutorial" taught about `waitForTransform()` and fixed a future extrapolation like so:

```
listener.waitForTransform("/turtle2", "/carrot1", rospy.Time(), rospy.Duration(4.0))
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    try:
        now = rospy.Time.now()
        listener.waitForTransform("/turtle2", "/carrot1", now, rospy.Duration(4.0))
        (trans,rot) = listener.lookupTransform("/turtle2", "/carrot1", now)
```

Based on that (which worked) and the changes shown above, here is my full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import tf
import turtlesim.srv
import geometry_msgs.msg
import math

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('tf_turtle')

    listener = tf.TransformListener()

    rospy.wait_for_service('spawn')
    spawner = rospy.ServiceProxy('spawn', turtlesim.srv.Spawn)
    spawner(4, 2, 0, 'turtle2')

    turtle_vel = rospy.Publisher('turtle2/cmd_vel',
                                 geometry_msgs.msg.Twist,
                                 queue_size=1)

    rate = rospy.Rate(10)

    listener.waitForTransform('/turtle2', '/carrot1',
                              rospy.Time().now(),
                              rospy.Duration(4.0))

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        try:
            now = rospy.Time.now() - rospy.Duration(5.0)
            listener.waitForTransform('/turtle2', '/carrot1', now, rospy.Duration(1.0))
            (trans, rot) = listener.lookupTransform('/turtle2',
                                                    '/carrot1',
                                                    now)
        except(tf.LookupException, tf.ConnectivityException, tf.ExtrapolationException):
            continue

        angular = 4 * math.atan2(trans[1], trans[0])
        linear = 0.5 * math.sqrt(trans[0] ** 2 + trans[1] ** 2)
        cmd = geometry_msgs.msg.Twist()
        cmd.linear.x = linear
        cmd.angular.z = angular
        turtle_vel.publish(cmd)

        rate.sleep()
```

I'm getting these types of errors about past extrapolation when I run the above:

```
listener.waitForTransform('/turtle2', '/carrot1', now, rospy.Duration(1.0))
tf.Exception: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1498858934.730669022 but the earliest data is at time 1498858934.911530972, when looking up transform from frame [carrot1] to frame [turtle2]. canTransform returned after 1.00266 timeout was 1.
```

I've tried inserting a `rospy.sleep(5)` above the `while` section to ensure that there's 5 seconds of data, as well as having the first call to `waitForTransform` use `rospy.Time.now() - rospy.Duration(5.0)` to match the second argument. I'm not really sure what's going on. The tutorial goes on to suggest this is not really what you want anyway, but it still shows it like it should run so I'm confused at my results!

---

**EDIT:** I've left the original question as-is, but wanted to respond to the comments by making this more reproducible. I started over from the beginning, creating versions of each file as I went. These are now [on github](https://github.com/jwhendy/learning_tf). If you want to reproduce:

```
git clone https://github.com/jwhendy/learning_tf.git
cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin build ## or catkin_make
roslaunch learning_tf start_demo.launch
```

The [log file](https://pastebin.com/EBRfiQrk) may be of interested too (should have checked this initially):

```
[rospy.internal][WARNING] 2017-07-03 13:48:03,104: Unknown error initiating TCP/IP socket to hostname:36627 (http://hostname:38196/): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_base.py", line 557, in connect
    self.read_header()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_base.py", line 650, in read_header
    self._validate_header(read_ros_handshake_header(sock, self.read_buff, self.protocol.buff_size))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'buff_size'
 
[rospy.topics][ERROR] 2017-07-03 13:48:03,104: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 326, in close
    c.close()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_base.py", line 838, in close
    self.socket.close()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
```

One last thing I wondered about... Section 1 has this:

```
listener.waitForTransform("/turtle2", "/carrot1", now, rospy.Duration(1.0))
(trans, rot) = listener.lookupTransform("/turtle2", "/carrot1", now)
```

Section 2, the supposed fix has this:

```
listener.waitForTransformFull("/turtle2", now,
                              "/turtle1", past,
                              "/world", rospy.Duration(1.0))
(trans, rot) = listener.lookupTransformFull("/turtle2", now,
                                            "/turtle1", past,
                                            "/world")
```

Is this correct (referencing a transform between `turtle2` and the `carrot1` frame at first, but then comparing `turtle2` and `turtle1` for the "fix")? Neither the original example which is supposed to show `turtle2` going crazy, or the sane behavior in Section 2 work for me; I get past extrapolation for both.

I've left the current version of `*.py` as the status after [time travel with tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Time%20travel%20with%20tf%20%28Python%29), Section 1.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265272/tf-transform-tutorial-issue-(past-extrapolation)/) by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2017-06-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-07-03**:
Re your edit about log files: If you're having errors with urls like "http://hostname:38196/" you need to double check your network setup. You should see valid hostnames there not the string "hostname".

**Comment by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on 2017-07-03**:
That was intentional. I'm not network savvy and am not sure what constitutes something I don't want floating around on the internet. I used `username` and `hostname` as generic fill-ins.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-07-03**:
If you do that please mention it so that it's clear to those of us trying to help you.

**Comment by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on 2017-07-03**:
Will do. I thought cloning/reproducing was the best way to just get to whether this is an issue or not... can you reproduce the error, or does it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're off by 2 tenths of a second still. Waiting will almost never resolve an extrapolation into the past.

My guess is that you'll get that error for a little bit, and then it will go away as time moves forward and the cache extends beyond 5 seconds into the past.

Your posted code isn't printing the exceptions so I'm guessing there are other local changes besides the sleep.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on 2017-07-03**:
Sorry; should have posted the full error. `turtle_tf_listener` dies after the above. Full error is [here](https://pastebin.com/aXXSgX0H). I'm not sure what exceptions I should see instead. Also, I pushed this all to github if you want to replicate. You can check for 'local changes' this way, too.